How to Use Firebase Authentication with JS File?
createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not defined
How can I access the auth object initialized in index.html within my auth.js file? Should I pass it as an argument, or is there a better way to manage the Firebase authentication in a modular JavaScript setup? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
<form id="signup-form">
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="email" id="signup-email" required />
        <label for="signup-email">Email address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
        <input type="password" id="signup-password" required />
        <label for="signup-password">Password</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>

<script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.14.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAuth } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.14.1/firebase-auth.js";

    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "API_KEY",
        authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
        projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
        storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
        messagingSenderId: "MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
        appId: "APP_ID",
        measurementId: "MEASUREMENT_ID"
    };

    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);  // Initializes the auth service
</script>
<script src="scripts/auth.js"></script>

const signupForm = document.querySelector('#signup-form');

signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = signupForm['signup-email'].value;
    const password = signupForm['signup-password'].value;

    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((cred) => {
        console.log(cred);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error creating user:", error);
    });
});


In order to be able to call createUserWithEmailAndPassword, you need to import that specific function in the specific file where you want to call it. So similar to how you import-and-then-call getAuth in the first file, you'll need to import-and-then-call createUserWithEmailAndPassword in the second file too.
Mark auth.js as a module in the HTML (so that you can use import in it):
<script src="scripts/auth.js" type="module"></script>

And then in auth.js itself
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.14.1/firebase-auth.js";

And then:
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(getAuth(), email, password).then((cred) => {
  ...


I don't want to make my auth.js file a module. Is there a way to make it work without using modules?

You mean like with the compat libraries shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade?

You might also want to see if it still works with require: something like const { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } = require('firebase/auth');
